# Mostrar todas as possibilidades de números em Python

Tags: python, array, matriz, for, while

Como eu faço para mostrar todas as possibilidades de acordo com o número de quantização de bits, por exemplo:
user: 8 níveis
bits: 3
preciso mostrar então:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

meu código até o momento, e precisa ser sem usar muitas funções prontas, modo raiz mesmo. me ajudem por favor:

```
while True:
    nbits = 0
    niveis = int(input('Digite os niveis de quantização:'))
    q = niveis
    v = ""
    if niveis < 0:
        print("Números negativos não são permitidos")
    elif niveis == 0:
        nbits = 1
        print("O número de bits: ", nbits )
    elif niveis == 1:
        nbits = 2
        print("O número de bits: ", nbits )
    elif niveis%2 == 0:
        while (niveis>1):
            niveis = niveis/2
            nbits = (nbits + 1)
        print("O número de bits: ", nbits )
        print("Possibilidades")
    matriz = [[q],[nbits]]
    for l in range(1, q):
        for c in range(0, nbits):
            if l == 1:
                v += ("0")
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para N bits, o maior valor possível é 2<sup>N</sup> - 1, então basta fazer um loop até esse valor e imprimir o valor em binário:

```
niveis = int(input('Digite os niveis de quantização:'))
for i in range(2 ** niveis):
    print(f'{i:0{niveis}b}')
```

Saída (para `niveis` igual a 3, por exemplo):

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

O formato `0{niveis}b` mostra o número em binário, usando uma quantidade de espaços igual a `niveis` e completando com zeros à esquerda caso necessário. [Veja a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) para saber mais.

---

Mas se quiser imprimir com um espaço entre os dígitos, bastaria manipular a string:

```
for i in range(2 ** niveis):
    print(' '.join(c for c in f'{i:0{niveis}b}'))
```

Outra alternativa é usar [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), que já gera todas as possibilidades pra você:

```
from itertools import product
niveis = int(input('Digite os niveis de quantização:'))
for i in product('01', repeat=niveis):
    print(' '.join(i))
```

`product` retorna tuplas contendo zeros e uns, então basta juntá-los com `join`, que os elementos serão separados por um espaço. A saída dos 2 códigos acima - para `niveis` igual a 3 - é:

```
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo.